# Podio widget update order

Tags: php, ruby, widget, podio

According to this doc: [Update widget order](https://developers.podio.com/doc/widgets/update-widget-order-22495)

we need to pass 3 arguments when firing the method

```
PodioWidget::update_order( ref_type, ref_id, widget_list )
```

I have set the update like

```
PodioWidget::update_order('space', 5293048, 
  array('widget_list' => array ( 586125, 586124, 586121 )))
```

> Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Invalid value {"widget_list": [586125,
>   586124, 586121]} (object): must be array"

What should be the 3rd parameter, what should it look like?

Comment: Did you try `PodioWidget::update_order('space', 5293048, [586125, 586124, 586121])` ? What do you get?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš, yes, I've try that and got an error 
Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Invalid value [586125, 586124, 586121] (array): must be integer"

Comment: Your original code didn't work because you created a multi-dimensional array.

Just on a hunch, could you try Md. Farhan Memon's suggestion using long-form array syntax? (Older versions of PHP don't support the short-form syntax.)

`PodioWidget::update_order('space', 5293048, array(586125, 586124, 586121))`

Comment: Already test it but does not work

Comment: Can you please share error messages that you are getting for each case?

Comment: For the `PodioWidget::update_order('space', 5293048, array(586125, 586124, 586121))` I got this response [http://prnt.sc/f4e970](http://prnt.sc/f4e970)

Comment: So, you got a successful 204 reply. Do you see widget's order updated now?